# Proving equality in measure theory

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f$ be an integrable function over $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that
$$
\lim _{k \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x-k) \frac{x}{1+|x|} d x=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) d x .
$$

i cant transform $f(x-k)\frac{x}{1+|x|}$ in a sequence to use some convergence theorem. Can somebody help me? thanks a lot

Comment: @FShrike it indeed does. It is undeniably true if $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. But I am not sure wheter just integrability is enough.

Comment: @Alastor Assuming $f \in L^1$, you can make the substitution $u = x - k$.

Answer (score 3):

For $f\in L_1(\mathbb{R},\lambda)$. By translation invariance of the Lebesgue measure
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x-k)\frac{x}{1+|x|}\,dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\frac{x+k}{1+|x+k|}\,dx$$
Notice that $\Big|f(x)\frac{x+k}{1+|x+k|}\Big|\leq |f(x)|$. By dominated convergence
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x-k)\frac{x}{1+|x|}\,dx\xrightarrow{k\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\,dx$$